# copying objects to array and then destroying them in Objective C

Tags: ios, class, object

Perhaps this is a dumb question, I just can't figure out the elegant or standard way to do this.

I have a custom class called Segment. In my main program, I have a property called @currentSegment which is of the type Segment.

Sometimes my user will do something that creates a Segment (which will be self.currentSegment), then later they will need to create a new segment but I need to store the old Segment (in a NSMutableArray I guess). I don't know how many Segments the user will ever create, it could be hundreds.

Should I just stick every Segment into the NSMutableArray as soon as I create the Segment, and then refer to them as [segmentArray lastObject], and not even use currentSegment is that a good programming practice?

I am sorry for simple questioning, I think so hard but feel I am overlooking easy solution.

Comment: Maybe show some additional code to make it a bit clear what you're looking for.

Comment: Your array idea seems reasonable.  What happens to previous segments...do you ever save or access them?

Comment: I do access them yes. I need to keep track of them because I will have to use them at the end.

Comment: I know the some people use that method, like in this example (sockets though) : https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/blob/master/GCD/Xcode/EchoServer/EchoServerAppDelegate.m  (connectedSockets)